# How to import a list?

Tags: list

I have a file (myWords.txt) which contains one word on each line :

```
Word 1
Word 2
---
---
Word 3000
```

With this file, I create a list :

```
function! MyFunction()
        let start = reltime()
        exe 'e myWords.txt'
        let myList = []
        exe '%s/.*/\=add(myList, submatch(0))/g'
        exe 'bd!'
        echom printf('Duration = %s seconds', reltimestr(reltime(start))) 
endfunction
```

It takes me 34.1666367 seconds

What can I do to download my list more quickly ? Could you help me, please ?

Answer (score 6):

> I have a file (myWords.txt) which contains one word on each line

Then simply

```
let mylist = readfile('myWords.txt')
```

Comment: Note that for the current buffer we can directly use `getline(1, '$')`. and there are other functions to fetch the lines in the other loaded buffers. See `:h functions`

Answer (score 3):

[Matt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23317/343) is the *best* way to do this, but here's an alternative. After you load your file into the buffer, you can call [`getline()`](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29) which returns the lines you ask for as a List:

```
let myList = getline(1, '$')
```

As a side note, I'd also like to point out that none of your uses of `exe` are necessary. You can write all of these Ex commands directly into your function:

```
    e myWords.txt
    %s/.*/\=add(myList, submatch(0))/g
    bd!
```

Comment: To be fair, `:exe` becomes necessary when the pattern is a variable. But then we could also play with `getline()`/`readfile()` + `filter()`.